# T-Test Raw Data vs Sampling Data with CLT

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, central-limit-theorem

I have some data that I want to run a T-Test on and get a p-value of 0.05.  See below:

[image]

I then using the CLT take 30 samples from each sample and take the mean of each sample.  I do this 100 times to get 2 new samples.

When I do this I get a much smaller p-value.

[image]

My question: Is it correct, from a statistical standpoint, to take a T-Test of 2 approximations using the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: You should be able to answer this yourself simply by varying your experiment.  *E.g.*, what happens to the p-value when you increase the subsample size from 30 to 300 and then to 3000?

Comment: When I choose different subsample sizes and I get different p-values, what should I be looking for?   I guess my question is, which is more accurate?  My original data that has a p-value of 0.05 or my sampled data with a p-value of 1.3*10^-15?

Comment: I was hoping it would be apparent that when your answer depends on an arbitrary element of your procedure, such as what size of a subsample to take, that answer is meaningless.